# Need a regex expression finds all the words of length 8 that contain a and e

Tags: regex, grep

I'm just using a grep command to do this.
I'm not sure how to write the regex expression to find all words of length 8 that contain specific letters `a` and `e` anywhere in the string.

`\b\w{8}\b`  - gets all the 8 character words but how do you further filter to remove all those that don't contain `a` or `e`.

```
elephant - good
elafna   - bad  too short
aassdddd - bad needs to contain e
```

Comment: Try 
(?!.*[ae].*)\b\w{8}\b

Comment: i tried that it didn't work

Comment: `grep '^.\{8\}$' words.txt | grep '[ae]'`?

Comment: Did you try grep with PCRE syntax?

Comment: that returns words with a or e or both

Comment: Try: `grep -oE '\b\w{8}\b' File | grep a | grep e`

Comment: Or (?i)\b[b-df-z\d]{8}\b

Comment: What platform are you working on and which grep? Please edit your question, adding the results of `uname -a` and `grep --version` (if the latter works).

Answer (score 0):

If grep -P is supported to make use of PCRE regex, you could use

```
\b(?=\w{8}\b)(?=\w*a)\w*e\w*\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?=\w{8}\b)` Positive lookahead, assert 8 word chars followed by a word boundary directly to the right
- `(?=\w*a)` Positive lookahead, assert an `a` char to the right
- `\w*e\w*` Match 0+ times a word char, match an `e` char and again 0+ times a word char
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R4NUZU/1)

For example

```
grep -oP "\b(?=\w{8}\b)(?=\w*a)\w*e\w*\b" words.txt
```

Output

```
elephant
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
grep -oE '\b[[:alnum:]_]{8}\b' words.txt | grep '[ae]'
```

The `\b[[:alnum:]_]{8}\b` pattern matches 8-word character words and then the second `grep` only keeps those words that contain either `a` or `e` letter.

[Test](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P70otUBBN99VQT0mKTraKjEnrzTXKjY@ttqiNiZJXcHGxkZBvTg1xcTUzNxCIQmoJd7QyFihsNy4qKSyNFNdoUYBbIJ6dGJqrPr//wA):

```
grep -oE '\b[[:alnum:]_]{8}\b' <<< 'sed45678 bash_123 qw3rtyui' | grep '[ae]'
```

Result:

```
sed45678
bash_123
```